# How do you sign transactions from a HD wallet?

Tags: transactions, private-key, bitcoinjs

I'm using the following tool to generate a HD wallet:
https://iancoleman.io/bip39/

However, it gives quite a few different private keys and I'm not sure which one is used to sign transactions with.

I'm using the bitcoinjs-lib to create an EC pair but I'm not sure how to go from the private keys generated to a hexidecimal string:

https://github.com/bitcoinjs/bitcoinjs-lib/blob/master/test/ecpair.js#L29

Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to sign with the HD private keys you generated on the site?

Comment: If so, you will need to extract the private key from the HD private keys (in Extended Key format), which are encoded like this: https://teachbitcoin.io/wallets.html#/9

Comment: Yes, thanks that's a great resource! I'll look into extracting the private key from the extended key format. Do I extract from the account extended key or the BIP32 one?

Comment: Extended keys are described in BIP32, and which private key u need to sign with depends on the output. In addition to priv/pubkey, extended keys simply contain the chaincode information required to derive further children. There is a master extended key pair from which all children are derived. The account key I presume u mean the parent of all child keys in that acct, such as m/44’/0’/0’/0?

Comment: "which private key u need to sign with depends on the output" -> I assume it is because you need to sign with the specific private key that generates the address that the input is coming from?

Comment: I'm still not sure how to get to the hexadecimal string as used in: https://github.com/bitcoinjs/bitcoinjs-lib/blob/master/test/ecpair.js#L29

I managed to find the bip32 site: http://bip32.org

Comment: I wrote my question a bit differently here: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/83477/deriving-hex-private-key-from-a-hd-wallet